# While using trigger on MariaDB: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: java, sql, triggers, mariadb

The error that I get is on the following: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_update_balance AFTER INSERT ON transact'"
THE sql statement that I tried:

```
String triggerForBalance = "DELIMITER $$" +
                " CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_update_balance " + 
                "AFTER INSERT ON transaction" +
                "FOR EACH ROW" +
                "BEGIN" +
                "IF NEW.betslip_id != NULL THEN" +
                "UPDATE user SET balance = balance - NEW.amount_of_cost;" +
                "END$$" +
                "DELIMITER ;";
```

What is the reason of this error?
If it is related with my MariaDB version how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: most likely the problem is not with a query itself but with execution engine (maybe some escaping?). How does this query run outside your java env? (f.e. call it directly to DB server with native client)

Comment: ...and close the `IF` with `END IF;` between the `UPDATE` and `END$$`, but `END$$` should be `END;$$` too.